# jQuery + datepicker extreme slowness in Google Apps Script

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, google-caja

I have the following script, which makes a sliding form using jquery and a datepicker implemented.

It performs awfull, even so much I get Chrome to crash. I suspect something is wrong, but I cannot see what is happening. In the caja playground it is not utterly fast, but better.

Maybe anyone sees what happens here?

The script:
https://script.google.com/a/zzapps.nl/d/1IH5NSQlmv7LG5mUWAJTsIupIA8xOo_qXYyrEgvzP_d5TvYAwl4_eJaPV/edit

The published webapp:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyKFV8tDkqcZs6aDF3hVmO5f-2RPZHMnrQgZuRWMkR4x6Q1TpVu/exec

Answer (score 3):

The Caja playground defaults to "ES5" mode if you don't change the drop down on the top, which is a different way of using Caja than what Apps Script uses ("ES53" mode in that dropdown). I suspect that in the latter mode you'd see the same on the playground. But we are aware of the slowness and working on it.

Comment: Yes, but like 2 or 3 second slowness is okay. But it is more like 10 second, and the fan of my Chromebox starts blowing very hard.

It is not that big stuff happening is it? Or can this be?

Comment: 2 or 3 seconds is not ok either :). We are really truly working on speeding this all up.

Comment: Haha I believe you. But still I was wondering if in this case there was more wrong... did you 'try' the link?

Comment: Yes, I did. I don't think you did anything wrong (although I can't seem to view the 'edit' link). I think you've hit a bug of ours, and I am investigating it.

Comment: is there any workaround for it? 
any other kind of data picker that would work faster?
Thanks!

Comment: If you mean by 'other kind of' I'd suggest 3 <select> boxes: year, month, day.